# .py to apk on pydrion or on pydriod any method not working

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, apk

Hey I make two games (snake game and dino game ) with python on pydriod app because I haven't any pc or laptop
I want to convert these games to apk but I can't convert

Any way to conver .py to .apk on android